# Can not find class JUNIT and linux

Tags: java, linux, junit

I have command

```
sudo /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -cp "/opt/workproject/lib/junit-4.10.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test
```

When I try to run I get:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: test
```

If I try to run

```
sudo /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -cp "/opt/workproject/lib/junit-4.10.jar,/opt/workproject/test-java/test.class" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test
```

I have :

```
Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

I have all permissions rwx all groups I had execute `chmode 777` on folder with libs and Test.class as well

Why I do have this problem, please help

Comment: 1/ classpath separator is `:` on linux, 2/ you need to add "/opt/workproject/test-java/" to the classpath (NB: it's a directory)

Answer (score 0):

standard way to run tests is either

- running them in your IDE (eclipse/intelliJ)
- running them with `mvn clean test`

I'd recommend that you should try one of these solutions first. They are much friendlier to developer than maintenance of tons of scripts for each test.